# For what value of the constant $p$ does the line $X$ and the plane $X_{2}$ not intersect?

Tags: geometry, vectors

For what value of the constant $p$ does the line $X$ and the plane $X_{2}$ not intersect?

$X : (4, 0, 1)+t(2, 5, p)$

$X_{2} : x+2y+3z=8$

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Please invest some effort in formatting your questions. It is hardly readable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the line $X$ does not intersect the plane $X_2$, then the line is parallel to the plane.  In particular, the direction of $X$ is perpendicular to the *normal vector* of $X_2$.